# DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit

Tags: spock, grails-3.0

I have a grails 3 project where I had to write a regular Spring MVC @RestfulController (for Chunk json response reasons). Anyway I tried to write a simple Spock unit test for the simple controller actions. They run fine inside IDEA but out on the command line they fail with strange errors related to asm/cglib from what i have read.  Anyone know how I can get around this ?

Test the advanced search action returns a page of results

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory$ConstructorFriendlyEnhancer
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:80)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:45)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:281)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:83)
    at uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.controller.SearchControllerSpec.setup(SearchControllerSpec.groovy:27)
```

Test the basic search action returns a page of results

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:80)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:45)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:281)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:83)
    at uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.controller.SearchControllerSpec.setup(SearchControllerSpec.groovy:27)
```

Here is my test:

```
package uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.controller

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest
import spock.lang.Specification
import uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.command.AdvancedSearchCommand
import uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.command.BasicSearchCommand
import uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.search.SearchService
import uk.ac.xxx.coursefinder.solr.domain.CourseGuide

/**
 * Pure unit test
 */


class SearchControllerSpec extends Specification {

    SearchController searchController = new SearchController()

    SearchService searchService

    def setup() {
        searchService = Mock()
        searchController.searchService = searchService
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }


    def "Test the basic search action returns a page of results"() {

        given:
        print "1"
        Page expectedPage = new PageImpl<CourseGuide>([new CourseGuide()])
        BasicSearchCommand basicSearchCommand = new BasicSearchCommand()
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 20)

        when: "The basic search action is executed with a BasicSearchCommand"

        Page page = searchController.basic(basicSearchCommand, pageRequest)

        then: "The correct search service was called with the appropriate arguments and returned expected results"

        1 * searchService.basic(basicSearchCommand, pageRequest) >> expectedPage
        page == expectedPage

    }

    def "Test the advanced search action returns a page of results"() {

        given:
        print "2"
        Page expectedPage = new PageImpl<CourseGuide>([new CourseGuide()])
        AdvancedSearchCommand advancedSearchCommand = new AdvancedSearchCommand()
        PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 20)

        when: "The advanced search action is executed with a AdvancedSearchCommand"

        Page page = searchController.advanced(advancedSearchCommand, pageRequest)

        then: "The correct search service was called with the appropriate arguments and returned expected results"

        1 * searchService.advanced(advancedSearchCommand, pageRequest) >> expectedPage
        page == expectedPage

    }


}
```

and my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.6.4"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.craigburke.gradle:karma-gradle:1.4.3"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.craigburke.gradle:bower-installer-gradle:2.5.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.2"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.0.4"
        classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.1"
    }
}


version "0.1"
group "coursefinder.grails.angular"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"com.craigburke.karma"
apply plugin:"com.craigburke.bower-installer"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json"
apply plugin:"net.saliman.cobertura"


ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven { url "http://maven.restlet.org" } //needed for solr core lib
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    assets "com.craigburke.angular:angular-template-asset-pipeline:2.2.6"
    assets "com.craigburke.angular:angular-annotate-asset-pipeline:2.4.0"
    assets "com.craigburke:js-closure-wrap-asset-pipeline:1.2.0"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:views-json"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"

    //solr and rest stuff
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-solr')

    //for embedded server
    compile ('org.apache.solr:solr-core:4.10.4') {
        exclude(group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-jdk14")
        exclude(group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic")
    }

    compile "org.grails.plugins:grails3-cas-client:3.0"
    compile "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2"


    profile "org.grails.profiles:angular:3.1.3"
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"


    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    //testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
    //testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'

    //testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    //testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"


    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:grails-console:2.0.4'

    //testRuntime "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10" //stop cobertura class not found exception


}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}
bower {
    'angular'('1.4.x') {
        source 'angular.js'
    }
    'angular-resource'('1.4.x') {
        source 'angular-resource.js' >> '/angular/'
    }
    'angular-route'('1.4.x') {
        source 'angular-route.js' >> '/angular/'
    }
    'angular-mocks'('1.4.x') {
        source 'angular-mocks.js' >> '/angular/'
    }
    'angular-bootstrap'('1.1.x') {
        source 'ui-bootstrap-tpls.js' >> '/angular/'
    }
    'bootstrap'('3.x.x') {
        source 'dist/css/bootstrap.css' >> '/bootstrap/'
    }
}

karma {
    dependencies(['karma-wrap-preprocessor'])

    profile 'angularJS'

    preprocessors = [
        'grails-app/assets/javascripts/**/*.js': ['wrap']
    ]

    wrapPreprocessor = [
        template: "(function () { 'use strict';  <%= contents %> })()"
    ]
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had a similar problem.

It seems that the `cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2` lib needs to be available at compile time. It is pulled in by the `org.grails:grails-plugin-testing` plugin.

I was able to solve it in two ways; both  involving the `dependencies {...}` block in `build.gradle`:

1) Add `compile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2'`

Or

2) Changing `testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"` to `compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"`

Hope it helps.